# Make the Y-axis scale exponentially in bar chart matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to plot some data using bar chart and it works fine, but the problem is that the difference is not recognizable from the graph as shown below, so I need to change the y axis scale to be exponential so the difference between the data can appear .. any help??
[image: bar chart]

This is my code:

```
    x = [0.1 1 10 100 1000 10000];
    y = [2.66    24.58    81.72    87.90    87.99    88.00];
    xplot = 1:numel(x); 
    figure;
    bar(xplot,y);
    set(gca,'XTick', xplot); 
    set(gca,'XTickLabel', x);
    ylim([0 100]);
```

Comment: Not sure what difference you're trying to show. Since the last three values are roughly the same, scaling the y-axis isn't going to adjust the visualization in any meaningful way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the `y`-axis to look more uniform, consider changing the scale to a semi-logarithmic plot, or transforming your `y` data through a `log` transformation:

## Option #1 - Change `y`-axis to `log` scale:

Simply obtain the current axes and set the `YScale` to `log`:

```
x = [0.1 1 10 100 1000 10000];
y = [2.66    24.58    81.72    87.90    87.99    88.00];
xplot = 1:numel(x); 
figure;
bar(xplot,y);
set(gca,'XTick', xplot); 
set(gca,'XTickLabel', x);
set(gca,'YScale','log'); %// NEW
%ylim([0 100]); %// Remove as we don't need it
```

This is what I get for the graph:

[image]

Be mindful that the `y`-axis doesn't change its data - only the way you present it.  The ticks are placed in a semi-logarithmic basis where from the bottom, we go from 1, 2, 3, up to 10 (`10^1`), next we go 20, 30, 40, up to 100 (`10^2`), then we go 200, 300, 400, up to 1000 (`10^3`) and so forth.  You can certainly see a pattern in the ticks, as we are increasing on a semi-logarithmic basis.

## Option #2 - Transform your `y`-data to `log`:

Just take your `y` data and run it through `log`:

```
x = [0.1 1 10 100 1000 10000];
y = [2.66    24.58    81.72    87.90    87.99    88.00];
xplot = 1:numel(x); 
figure;
bar(xplot,log(y)); %// NEW
set(gca,'XTick', xplot); 
set(gca,'XTickLabel', x);
%ylim([0 100]); %// Remove as we don't need it
```

This is what we get:

[image]

Be mindful that the `y`-axis has changed its units.  You can leave a disclaimer saying that your data was `log` transformed.

Comment: How do either of these change the interpretation of the visualization?

Comment: @KyleBooth it doesn't nor should it. I assumed the OP wants to change the scale so that the smaller values are more visible.

Comment: the first plot has no effect on visibility of smaller values... The second plot makes it difficult to discern the larger values (even with log transformation note). I feel like OP is probably thinking differently than he's asking.

Comment: @KyleBooth then you can go ahead and provide an answer! Have fun!